# UIRobot controller and program in C#

Tags: c#

I have this a controller from UIRobot. Here is manual: [enter link description here](http://driver232.rozek.sk/UIM241xx.pdf)
I want to write software to controle it in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace hhh   
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ot = "Port je otvoreny";
            string za = "Port je zavrety";
            string COM = "COM1";
            string command = "ENABLE";

            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(COM, 9600);
            sp.Open();

            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ot);
                sp.Write(command);
                sp.ReadLine();   
            }

            else
            {
                sp.Write(za);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

In manual is command ENABLE to initialize controller but it does not work in my code. How Can I send command or where I do a mistake?

---

I have learned something new so here is update my code and new question.
I want to recieve position of motor. There is command "POS;" which has to give me the value but I get message box with question mark (?) instead number value. Why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace UIRFocuser
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        enable.Enabled = true;
        disable.Enabled = false;
        zero.Enabled = false;
        increase.Enabled = false;
        inc10.Enabled = false;
        decrease.Enabled = false;
        dec10.Enabled = false;
        fbk.Enabled = false;
    }  
    private void enable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.PortName = "COM1";
        sp.BaudRate = 9600;
        int max = -7000; //max position motor
        int min = 0; //min positio of motor
        sp.Open();
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            enable.Enabled = false;
            disable.Enabled = true;
            zero.Enabled = true;
            increase.Enabled = true;
            inc10.Enabled = true;
            decrease.Enabled = true;
            dec10.Enabled = true;
            fbk.Enabled = true;

            sp.Write("ENABLE;");
        }
    }

    private void disable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            sp.Write("OFFLINE;");
            sp.Close();
            enable.Enabled = true;
            disable.Enabled = false;
            zero.Enabled = false;
            increase.Enabled = false;
            inc10.Enabled = false;
            decrease.Enabled = false;
            dec10.Enabled = false;
            fbk.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void zero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Write("POS0; SPD400;");          
    }

    private void increase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Write("STP1000; SPD400;");
    }

    private void inc10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Write("STP10; SPD400;");
    }

    private void decrease_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Write("STP-1000; SPD400;");
    }

    private void dec10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Write("STP10; SPD400;");
    }

    private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            sp.Write("OFFLINE;");
            sp.Close();
        }

        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void fbk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sp.Write("POS;");
        string msg = sp.ReadExisting();
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: This needs to spun of as an entirely new question, you have already accepted an answer on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that document, the command is "**ENABLE;**"  You have to include the semicolon. So change your code to:

```
string command = "ENABLE;";
```